# Why socket.io dont work( i can't connect or page still waiting forever) with two diferrent browser on the same pc

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, websocket, socket.io

My simple code for test is:
index.html

```
<script src="http://localhost:2020/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>

<script>
 socket = io('http://localhost:2020'/*,{secure: true}*/);
</script>
```

Note:I removed the secure true.

app.js Nodejs

```
var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    server = require('http').createServer(app),
    io = require('socket.io').listen(server),
    path = require("path");

app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));

server.listen(2020);
 console.log("localhost:2020");

io.on('connection', function(socket) {
    console.log("in");
    socket.on('disconnect',function(data){
        console.log("out");
    });
});
```

when I test the simple connection on my socket server with nodejs if i open a new page(new connection) on the different browser, example on chrome and other instance on opera the second instance don't work or have a block, don't open the page and don't call the socket.io server but when I open a new tab on chrome the new tabs with a new connection work fine....

note: the client page don't hosted on socket.io server because the client page it is hosted on apache server.

P1- I open index.html in Chome
= The page runs normally and the socket connects correctly

P2- I open index.html in a new Chrome tab
= The page runs the same normal and connects.

P3- I open index.html in an incognito chrome or open on Opera (other browser)
= The socket is not connected and the page is blocked

P4-I do (refresh) a socket that I opened in chrome(P2) that is, I refresh the new chrome tab.
The socket server is still blocked and does not even connect.

P5- I refresh the page of (P1):
= everything is unlocked and all the pages that are on the home page and are blocked now connect to the socket normally

happens if the index.html is hosted outside of NodeJS but if for example I create the index.html hosted for example in a Nodejs view it does not pass, the problem is that my application is thought of as a widget that loads external to nodejs.

Answer (score -1):

secure option is for https connections and you are trying to connect to http. Try to remove secure option.